# Python: SelectField "Not a valid choice"

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

**form.py**

```
class Confirm(CSRFForm):
    monitor_updates = SelectField(
        lazy_gettext("Monitor updates of an app"),
        validators=[validators.Optional()], choices=[], coerce=int
    )
```

**view.py**

```
def upload_confirm():
    form = Confirm()

    if form.validate_on_submit:
        if form.monitor_updates.data == 0:
            current_workflow.installation_source.monitor_updates_id = None
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            current_workflow.installation_source.monitor_updates_id = form.monitor_updates.data
            db.session.commit()

    choices = [(app[1][0], app[1][1]) for app in list_choices]
    form.monitor_updates.choices =[(0, "Nothing matches")]
    form.monitor_updates.choices += choices
```

**models.py**

```
class InstallationSource(db.Model):

    monitor_updates_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('updates_software.id'))
```

When filling out the form and selecting "Nothing matches" in the dropdown with a value of 0, I get an error.

[image: screenshot]

If you select a different value, the save is correct.
I can only use the number `0`, because all other numbers can be occupied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the logic for choices

```
    choices = [(app[1][0], app[1][1]) for app in list_choices]
    form.monitor_updates.choices =[(0, "Nothing matches")]
    form.monitor_updates.choices += choices
```

to come before the `form.validate_on_submit()` method:

```
def upload_confirm():
    form = Confirm()

    choices = [(app[1][0], app[1][1]) for app in list_choices]
    form.monitor_updates.choices =[(0, "Nothing matches")]
    form.monitor_updates.choices += choices

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.monitor_updates.data == 0:
            current_workflow.installation_source.monitor_updates_id = None
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            current_workflow.installation_source.monitor_updates_id = form.monitor_updates.data
            db.session.commit()
```

Comment: This makes perfectly sense as the changes are made only to the object and not to the class.